# Jquery changing div background depending on input value

Tags: jquery, css, forms, input

I've been struggling to get this, but finally, I won't be able to get it... ¿Could anyone help me with it?
What I wanted was to be able to change some  background depending on a input´s value. Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  $("#submit").click(function () {
    var whatLetter = $('input:text[name=fname]').val();
    switch (whatLetter) {
      case (whatLetter == "a"): 
        alert('A');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://www.royaltyfreespaceimages.com/imagenes/astronauts/astronauts_g/Astronaut-Outer-Space-Moon.jpg")');
        break;
      case (whatLetter == "b"):
        alert('B');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://www.hdimagewallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Space-Astronout-12-Cool-Wallpapers-HD.jpg")');
        break;
      default:
        alert('otro');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/doctorwho/images/c/c4/The-impossible-astronaut.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140808110916&path-prefix=es")');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#scene {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.video.hidden { display: none; }

#video {
  background-image: url('http://theincredibletide.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/astronaut-on-fire-by-jack-crossing.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div id="scene">
  <div class="video" id="video"></div>
</div>

<form action="#">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="txt_name"><br>
  <span id="submit">Vamos!</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong for your input. It should be `$('#txt_name');`

Your original one is `input:text[name=fname]'`, but if you want that to work it should be `input[name=fname]'` or just use the ID.

Also, your `switch` is wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#submit").click(function () {
    var whatLetter = $('#txt_name').val();
    switch (whatLetter) {
      case "a": 
        alert('A');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://www.royaltyfreespaceimages.com/imagenes/astronauts/astronauts_g/Astronaut-Outer-Space-Moon.jpg")');
        break;
      case "b":
        alert('B');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://www.hdimagewallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Space-Astronout-12-Cool-Wallpapers-HD.jpg")');
        break;
      default:
        alert('otro');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/doctorwho/images/c/c4/The-impossible-astronaut.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140808110916&path-prefix=es")');
    }
  });

});
```

When you use `case`, you don't need to do `WhatLetter == 'a'`, you can just put `'a'`, as the `switch` will be the value of `whatLetter` anyway.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sojjpaL/)

You can also do it in pure JavaScript, no need for jQuery:

```
(function(){
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
        var whatLetter = document.getElementById("txt_name").value,
            video      = document.getElementById("video");
        switch (whatLetter) {
            case 'a':
                alert('b');
                video.style.background = "url(http://www.royaltyfreespaceimages.com/imagenes/astronauts/astronauts_g/Astronaut-Outer-Space-Moon.jpg)";
            break;
            case 'b':
                alert('a');
                video.style.background = "url(http://www.hdimagewallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Space-Astronout-12-Cool-Wallpapers-HD.jpg)";
            break;
            default:
                alert('otro');
                video.style.background = "url(http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/doctorwho/images/c/c4/The-impossible-astronaut.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140808110916&path-prefix=es)";
        }
    }
})();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sojjpaL/1/)

Comment: I would also suggest to use them in onchange event.

Answer (score 0):

Case statement should be `case 'a':`, see code below and for the textvalue just use `$('input:text[name=fname]').val();`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  $("#submit").click(function () {
    var whatLetter = $('#txt_name').val();
    switch (whatLetter) {
      case 'a': 
        alert('A');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://www.royaltyfreespaceimages.com/imagenes/astronauts/astronauts_g/Astronaut-Outer-Space-Moon.jpg")');
        break;
      case 'b':
        alert('B');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://www.hdimagewallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Space-Astronout-12-Cool-Wallpapers-HD.jpg")');
        break;
      default:
        alert('otro');
        $("#video").css('background-image','url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/doctorwho/images/c/c4/The-impossible-astronaut.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140808110916&path-prefix=es")');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#scene {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.video.hidden { display: none; }

#video {
  background-image: url('http://theincredibletide.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/astronaut-on-fire-by-jack-crossing.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scene">
  <div class="video" id="video"></div>
</div>

<form action="#">
  <input type="text" id="txt_name"><br>
  <span id="submit">Vamos!</span>
</form>
```